# std::begin - User-defined overloads not considered in type traits

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

Consider following type trait:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_begin : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_begin<T, std::void_t<
    decltype(std::begin(std::declval<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>>()))
  >> : std::true_type {};
```

Why does this trait does not consider my user-defined overload for `std::begin`?

```cpp
namespace std {
void begin(foo&) {}
}

int main() {
  static_assert(has_begin<foo>::value); // Fails.

  foo f;
  std::begin(f); // Works.
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FNpnssxAnOtdoxfm)

Interesting observations:

1. if I change the order of this type trait and my overload, it works
2. if I use ADL in the type trait:

`decltype(std::begin(std::add_lva... -> decltype(begin(std::add_lva...`

it works if the free function `begin` is in the same namespace as *foo*:

```
void begin(foo) {
}
```

but fails for any class outside *std::* depending on:

```cpp
template<class C>
auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

because ADL lookup does not work with templates from other namespaces.

---

What could I do to support `std::begin(foo&)` in my type trait without changing the include order?

Otherwise I have to support both worlds - writing the type trait for std::begin and ADL begin()...

In my functions I already do something like this (suggested [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)):

```
auto get_begin() {
  using std::begin;
  return begin(object);
}
```

Comment: @uneven_mark You are though. There are exceptions and some are even encouraged.

Comment: Is std::begin allowed?I am usure, but here stands nothing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std - nevertheless the problem described could be happen with anything else than std::,

Comment: @uneven_mark There's a whole can of worms opening up when you get into the `unordered` things. Hashing ... you'll find yourself writing `namespace std { std::size_t my_hash...` quickly :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was aware that specializations on custom types are often allowed, e.g. `std::hash`, `std::swap`, but didn't realize that overloading `std::begin` was allowed.

Comment: @uneven_mark My knowledge about what the standard says is shallow. `std::begin` sounds reasonable to interfer with if you can make that work - but I don't know.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am going by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) right now. I have not found the relevant part of the standard yet.

Comment: @uneven_mark It's a super good wiki. The next standard proposal is also very useful: [C++ next draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/)

Comment: @TedLyngmo What I am missing in cppreference is references to the relevant standard sections. The library section on `std::begin` does not mention any special rules and [the general rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/constraints#namespace.std-1) seems to allow only specialization, not overload.

Comment: @uneven_mark There you go. I'm not a stickler for rules, but I hold cppref in high regards and tend to just go with the flow.

Comment: @uneven_mark: Then the rules are pretty clear: specialization, not overloading.

Comment: @NicolBolas Then cppreference got it wrong. I am not confident that I didn't miss some part of the standard, but if you agree that it isn't specifically allowed, then I might look into submitting an edit to cppreference.

Comment: @uneven_mark That's definitely an option. It'd be reviewed for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with a bit of indirection.

```
namespace adl {
  namespace std_adl {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    template<class T>
    auto adl_begin( T&& t )
    ->decltype(begin(std::forward<T>(t)) )
      { return begin(std::forward<T>(t)); }
    template<class T>
    auto adl_end( T&& t )
    ->decltype(end(std::forward<T>(t)) )
      { return end(std::forward<T>(t)); }
  }
  template<class T>
  auto begin(T&& t)
  ->decltype(std_adl::adl_begin(std::forward<T>(t)))
    { return std_adl::adl_begin(std::forward<T>(t)); }
  template<class T>
  auto end(T&& t)
  ->decltype(std_adl::adl_end(std::forward<T>(t)))
    { return std_adl::adl_end(std::forward<T>(t)); }
}
```

now use `adl::begin` in place of `std::begin` when you want to enable ADL, both in your `has_begin` type trait and at point of use.

As for this:

```
namespace std {
  void begin(foo&) {
  }
}
```

that makes your program ill-formed no diagnostic required.

Comment: Thank you. Great idea how to solve it. :) I didn't know std::begin is ill-formed because cppreference isn't so clear to me.

Comment: @viat don't add things to std except some specalizations in narrow cases (and never overloads)

Answer (score 6):

> What could I do to support std::begin(foo&) in my type trait without changing the include order?

You don't; `std::begin` is not meant to be called directly for arbitrary ranges. If you want to access `begin/end` for a range type, you're supposed to use ADL, combined with `using std::begin/end`. That's just how the idiom works in C++.

It is illegal to overload methods in the `std` namespaces, and `std::begin` is no exception. You can create a template specializations of `std`-defined templates (based on user-created types), but this is not the proper way to use the C++ idiom.

In C++20, the `std::ranges::begin` function is meant to be called directly, and the way you specialize it for a type is through ADL or a member `begin` function. So just use the idiom, and everyone will be fine.

Comment: Sorry for bargin in, but it's nice to have someone clarifying things. I willl return to this when `C++20` is a thing, for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. For me (and perhaps many others) it is not that clear described in cppreference. There is no explicit statement that `std::begin` should not called directly. Also overloading did mean for me implicit in the namespace of std. Thank you for mention `std::ranges::begin`, but this does not work for me yet: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tcv9KW